# Need a package for \bari

Tags: packages

I want to `\bari` code but I did found the package for this which is `wsuipa.sty`. Is there someone knows where we can download?

Comment: What is your platform? Try `texdoc wsuipa` in your terminal to read the manual. Otherwise, you can download it here: http://ctan.org/pkg/wsuipa

Comment: That depends on your used LaTeX distribution MikTeX has its own package manager, while TeXlive provides the `tlmgr` for package installation and updates.

Comment: @hakaze: I am using a Miktex

Comment: although the `wsuipa` fonts are on ctan, they appear to be available only in bitmap form.  the `tipa` fonts are more portable, and it appears that `\textbari` in `tipa` is equivalent to `\bari` in `wsuipa`.  even better, `tipa` is probably already available on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wsuipa` package is quite old and largely superseded by `tipa`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textbari

\textipa{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find the documentation for `tipa` on your system or at [this link](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/tipa/tipaman.pdf)